# Find only where the matching string is the first part of the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA to search a spreadsheet for the appearance of a string:

```
Range("A:A").Find(What:="B ", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
      LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
      MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

This works fine, but will pull up both "B xyz" and "xyzB abc." I only want the first instance, where there is nothing in front of the B. I know that if I wanted to find the second instance, I could use a wildcard in my What (e.g. "*B "), is there a "negative" character that I can use to indicate that "B " needs to be the first thing in the cell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the wildcard after the **B** with `xlWhole`:

```
Sub ngfdcvb()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A:A").Find(What:="B*", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
          LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
          MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

    MsgBox r.Value
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Don't know how I managed to overlook this simple solution! Thank you.